# Adding data to array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I need to add data to an array.
However, with my code: it overrides the data instead of appending it?

```
import UIKit
class Productreview: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var Item:String!   //Data from another viewcontroller
    var list:[String] = [] //The array



    //Update func
    func updatelist() {
        var listupdate = list
        listupdate.append(Item)
        list = listupdate
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updatelist()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    //Sets the tableView-data
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return (list.count)
    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
        return(cell)
    }
}
```

Comment: _Swift tip:_ variable names should always  be `lowerCamelCase` in Swift (`item` not `Item`)

Comment: The temporary variable is pointless. Just write `list.append(Item)` and then reload the table view. And `return` is not a function. Delete the parentheses (`return cell`)

Comment: I send data (String) to the var "item" from another viewcontroller, then I need to append that data to the array "list", to create the tableview

Comment: Your `updateList()` is only called *once,* when the view controller is loaded. And each instance of the view controller starts with an empty `list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks redundant.

```
func updatelist() {
    var listupdate = list
    listupdate.append(Item)
    list = listupdate
}
```

Why not just append it directly to the list?

```
func updatelist() {
    list.append(Item)
}
```

And i see that you are updating the list in `viewDidLoad`. So there will only be one `String` in the array. So my suspicion is that you create a new instance of `ProductReview` every time and not save the previous list anywhere. So what you need to do is save the list every time you append to it, but not inside `ProductReview`.

Now that i think about it. What is the use of the variable `Item` when you are only using it to append the value to the `list` in `viewDidLoad`?

**Solution:**

So, my suggestion would be that you form the list and pass the list to the `ProductReview` instance.

---

Sidenote: Like @AshelyMills pointed out in the comments, use *lowerCamelCase* for variables in Swift.

Comment: I did try to append it directly, but with the same output, override.
The use of "item" is for passing data from another viewcontroller I have, but it only passes a string.
That could be the solution, I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
class Productreview: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    // You have to write lowercase . Not write 'Item' 
    var item:String!   //Data from another viewcontroller
    var list:[String] = [] //The array

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // You have to define delegate and datasource
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        updatelist()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    //Update func
    func updatelist() {
        var listupdate = list
        listupdate.append(item)
        list = listupdate
        self.tableView.reloadData() // Dont forget this for showing elements.
    }

    //Sets the tableView-data
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return list.count
    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
        return cell 
    }
}
```

Comment: It still overrides the data given, but yes the I in item was a fail and is corrected